# Динамическое создание и заполнение Spinner-ов и получение выбранного в них элемента

Tags: android, android-spinner

В базе имеется большой многоуровневый список. В приложении мне надо запрашивать список каждого уровень, в зависимости от выбранного родительского уровня.

В приложении я создал Spinner, в который загружается список первого уровня, и  получаю id выбранного в Spinner "родителя".

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    new AsyncRequest1().execute();//запрос, на получение списка и заполнение Spinner в нем

    mySpinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            iing=(InventItemNumberGroup)mySpinner.getSelectedItem();
            selectID=iing.getItemId();//получение id выбранного родителя для дальнейших загрузок "дочерних" элементов
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

class AsyncRequest1 extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        try{
            ...
            myData=parser.list;//список для вывода в Spinner
            ArrayAdapter<InventItemNumberGroup> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<InventItemNumberGroup>(Second_activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myData);
            mySpinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);//заполнение Spinner'а
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Логика работы приложения такова: в первом Spinner выбирается значение, происходит запрос к базе, выбирается требуемый "дочерний список", строится новый Spinner, который заполняется этим списком, и у которого тоже есть setOnItemSelectedListener, в котором отслеживается выбранное значение в данном Spinner, и затем процесс повторяется, пока не достигается "дочерний элемент" без "детей".

Я не понимаю, каким образом реализовать данный процесс, с динамическим созданием на форме Spinner-ов, отправкой и получением данных из базы и отслеживание выбранного в созданном Spinner значения, для повторения операции. 
Мне кажется, что нужно использовать рекурсию или цикл, но не понимаю как это реализовать. Вообще. Подскажите, каким образом можно реализовать требуемую операцию?